# abstracting window and move semantics

Tags: c++, software-engineering

I am using GLFW to manage OpenGL context and as such, delegate this task to a GLFW window. For managing the pointer to a window instance, I am thinking a class like this:

```
class window_t {
public:
    using win_handle = GLFWwindow*;

    window_t(size_t width, size_t height, const std::string &title)
    {
        // Initialize GLFW
        if (!glfwInit())
            std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        // Set up OpenGl core profile
        ...

       // Open the window
       w = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title.c_str(), NULL, NULL);

       if (!w) {
            glfwTerminate();
            std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(w);
    }

    void swap_buffers()
    {
        glfwSwapBuffers(w);
    }

    void poll_events()
    {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    void terminate()
    {
        glfwTerminate();
    }
    bool about_to_close()
    {
        return glfwWindowShouldClose(w);
    }

private:
    win_handle w;
};
```

Think something similar. In my `display_t` class, I have an instance of `window_t` and an instance of `scene_graph`. Functions on my scene graph are like `render(window_t)`, `handle_input(window_t)` etc. What would my strategy should be in passing around these window instances? These are actually a handle to GLFW window and OpenGL context. It is not desirable to copy them because some parts of these context variables are living in VRAM and relates to GPU state. So if I want to change the context variables on say `handle_input(window_t)`, copying the window would defy the purpose. On the other hand, I don't want to pass raw pointers around. I can do a singleton maybe, considering I probably won't have multiple windows and OpenGL contexes. I am not really sure about this one though. And they say, singleton is as good as a global variable.

Maybe I should make `window_t` moveable but not copyable, making it hold a unique_ptr or something like that. I want to use value semantics as much as I can.

I really don't know the correct abstraction here. What would you suggest? Should I get rid of passing a handle to window to each object in scene graph? I am actually looking for a way to do this but all render calls, input handling etc. modifies the context variables. Want to hear your suggestions on this.

Comment: Making `window_t` movable-only is fine. Then you manage its lifetime like you would any other object's.

Comment: I am trying this but when I move, I set moved from object to nullptr. Then the global, singleton instance gets nullptr whenever I move.

Comment: That's because you're not following one of the guidelines for smart pointers: *only* use them when dealing with lifetimes. Does the function receiving the window have a say in its lifetime? Probably not: *you* just need to ensure that it lives longer than the function call. In that case, just pass a regular reference to the window.

Comment: Yeah, I am passing by reference for now and it works. I thought maybe there could be a way to pass window handles by value but this proves problematic since functions have no say in window object's lifetime.

Comment: My problem with the things as they are now is that, this window instance should be constructed at the beginning once and destructed at the end once. I don't know a way to implement copy/move constructors to fit into this scheme. Any call to these constructors messes up my program. Hence I pass only by reference.

Comment: First, determine exactly when are "the beginning" and "the end". I suppose they are respectively just after your library initializations, and just before their cleanup. Then, anchor this lifetime with one or more automatic objects -- If initialization and cleanup are called from the same function, a single, properly scoped object is enough. Finally, deal with accessing the window globally -- this can be as simple as setting a global pointer once the window is constructed, and resetting it just before it's destructed.

Comment: Do be careful in case your window object is moved around though: you do not want the global pointer to become dangling. A simple fix can be to dynamically allocate the window itself as an unmovable, uncopyable object, but manage its lifetime with a `std::unique_ptr`. Moving that `unique_ptr` won't disturb the window object, to which the global pointer can keep pointing still.